# How to set control properties in css?

Tags: asp.net, css, attributes

Is there a way to set this kind of properties in css? 
So I can use the same calendar and be more organized with my code

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Height="189px" CssClass="Calendar" 
                                ondayrender="CalendarRender"  TitleStyle-BackColor="#00718F"  TitleStyle-ForeColor="White" ShowGridLines="true" TitleStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" TitleStyle-BorderWidth="1px" TitleStyle-BorderColor="Black" SelectedDayStyle-ForeColor="#281dc9" SelectedDayStyle-Font-Bold="true" DayHeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black" DayHeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1px" DayHeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid"
                                onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: What kind of properties?? are you expecting `onselectionchanged` event to be in `css`??

Comment: clearly the style ones.. TitleStyle-BackColor="#00718F"  TitleStyle-ForeColor="White"  etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about properties such as:

```
    TitleStyle-BackColor="#00718F"  TitleStyle-ForeColor="White"
```

... etc..

Your best bet would be to render the calendar to a page, check its source and see what style it adds. You can then extract this out for use in CSS.

**UPDATE**

This page has some of the selector names for you, along with what they control [ASP.Net Calendar Control Custom Theme Format using CSS](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-Calendar-Control-Custom-Theme-Format-using-CSS.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!. I used .skin to do this, I made it work after a while.

Comment: Skins are very good too as they let you set the same selector name. Can be a bit of an arse if you need to fine tune though :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be more organized, and don't want your project to become like 'spaghetti' in future, use CSS file for css properties. Do not embed this properties in headers, unless this is the only way to solve current issue. This is bad for you, and for all who will work with your project.
I've met lot of legacy projects, wasting too much time to find why some dom element's behaviours differs from what I need.

Just specify `CssStyle` property in your aspx markup, and it will be mapped to real css class.

And add description for this class in css file.

Comment: This is exactly what he is asking.. I.E what does .Net call the CSS selectors so he can put it in CSS style sheet..

Comment: well, seem's that I've got it wrong. Edited post with how to manage it via css classes.